function calling in $(document).ready() vs $(document).ready(function() {})
I am using displayRows() function to add table body using document.ready. It was working fine for syntax : $(document).ready(function() as below
'$(document).ready(function() {
 function displayRows(){
var catRow = $('<tr class="category-row">'
+ '<th>'
+...........
+ '</th>'                                                         + '</tr>');
$('#cat tbody').append(catRow);
}
});`

But when I removed the function() as below, the table is not getting appended.
`$(document).ready(
function displayRows(){
var catRow = $('<tr class="category-row">'
+ '<th>'
+...........
+ '</th>'                                                         + '</tr>');
$('#cat tbody').append(catRow);
}
});`

Can anyone explain why it's not working in below case.
I expect it should work in same in both cases. As document.ready() require a function to be passed in it. And displayRows() function is still passed as a function to document.ready in second case.

As far as I can tell, the first one should not work, as it's a function in a function, and the inner function is not called. Of course, what "works" and "not works" means is not clear, as there is no information given in the question.

@Pointy The first one is working i.e. function in function. But second one is not working.

you directly pass displayRows() to $(document).ready(), which means displayRows() is treated as the ready handler itself. This will work only if displayRows() is defined in such a way that it takes no arguments and is meant to be executed as soon as the DOM is ready.
one option to make this work is this:
$(document).ready(function() {
    function displayRows(){
        var catRow = $('<tr class="category-row">'
            + '<th>'
            + '...'
            + '</th>'
            + '</tr>');
        $('#cat tbody').append(catRow);
    }
    
    displayRows();
});

another way to do it is to directly pass displayRows() as the ready handler:
function displayRows(){
    var catRow = $('<tr class="category-row">'
        + '<th>'
        + '...'
        + '</th>'
        + '</tr>');
    $('#cat tbody').append(catRow);
}

$(document).ready(displayRows);

